# mod_fastcgi to mod_fcgid

Tags: fastcgi, mod-fcgid, mod-fastcgi

I had a server running as a fastcgi application with mod_fastcgi.

```
FastCgiServer /opt/rok4/bin/rok4 -init-start-delay 5 -port 1998 -processes 2
```

The idea beeing that mod_fastcgi launches the server instances at startup and provides port number.

How can I replicate this behaviour with the "new" mod_fcgid ?

Thanx in advance

Manu

Answer (score 0):

You can't, `fgdid` doesn't support TCP sockets. See http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=450748